# A Database Error Occurred: You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, database, api, codeigniter, model

This is the code:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
return $this->db->update('contractors', ((array) $contractor));
```

And it gives me the error `A Database Error Occurred: You must use the "set" method to update an entry.`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing the `$contractor` array so I might be wrong here, but when I get this error in CI, it's usually because I dont' have my update/insert data array correctly formatted with key/value pairs.

```
$contractor = array(
"name" => "John",
"phone" => "123-123-1234"
);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
return $this->db->update('contractors', $contractor);
```

Comment: Okay that is what I thought. But the thing is I am using Postman for sending API request. When I use 'echo' for printing the $contractor details, nothing is being printed. I am relatively new to Postman and PHP so it is more tough lol